# How to test and discover dependency between time series?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, data-analysis

$x_1(t), x_2(t), x_3(t), ...$ are independent variables, and $y(t)$ is another variable I suspect to be dependent. I have dataset of the evolution of $x_1(t), x_2(t), x_3(t), ..., y(t)$ over time in many different experiments. The questions are: how do I test if $y(t)$ is dependent on $x_1(t), x_2(t), x_3(t), ...$?. How do I discover such relationship?

Suppose I wanted to train a ML model that accepts $x_1(t), x_2(t), x_3(t), ...$ as input and predicts $y(t)$ as output. What exactly is the name of this problem? I get confused with names such as univariate/multivariate time series forecasting and multiple/linear regression. It seems to me that "forecasting" is a type of problem where you already have a history of the time series to predict $y(t)$; instead, I need to predict $y(t)$ from `t=0` to the end. Is it still forecasting? Do you know any example/resources of this kind of problem solved in keras/tensorflow? Should I consider using LSTMs or any other RNN model?

Comment: How can you forecast y if you have no data about y?

Comment: I understand from your comment that my problem is not called forecasting then. `y` is predictable because it is dependent from `x1, x2, x3, ...`

Comment: Predictable how? What is the relationship?

Comment: The relationship is what I am trying to discover, maybe with LSTM or any other RNN.

Comment: You either: 1) have the data but don't know the relationship -> the goal then is to mathematically formulate this relationship, 2) have the relationship but not the data -> the goal then is to get the data. If you have neither the data nor the relationship then there is noting to do. So which is it?

Comment: I have the data and don't know te relationship. I want to predict $y$ in experiments where I don't have any data about $y$

Comment: If you have data about $y$ and you want to use this to make predictions about the future where you do not have data about $y$, then this is forecasting; if you are trying to make predictions about the present/past (where you also do not have data about $y$) then this is predicting.